# Подключение Яндекс.Карт к проекту Blazor Server

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api, blazor

Задача - использование минимального функционала Яндекс.Карт в проекте Blasor Server.
Яндекс.Карты подключаются двумя файлами - html и js, процедура подробно описана здесь https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/mapbasics/, но повторю:

***mapbasics.js***

```
// Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с
    // заданным id ("map").
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        // При инициализации карты обязательно нужно указать
        // её центр и коэффициент масштабирования.
        center: [55.76, 37.64], // Москва
        zoom: 10
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });

    document.getElementById('destroyButton').onclick = function () {
        // Для уничтожения используется метод destroy.
        myMap.destroy();
    };
}
```

***mapbasics.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Создание и удаление</title>
    <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=<ваш API-ключ>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="mapbasics.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 90%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <input type="button" id="destroyButton" value="Удалить карту"/>
</body>

</html>
```

В оффлайн эта пара работает отлично, и на статическом сайте, наверное, тоже. А в Blazor проблемы. Файл html переформатируется в страницу Razor, но:

Проблема 1.
Blazor не терпит тегов *script*. Интернет советует перенести теги *script* в конец тега *body*. Это не работает, работает совет Blazor'а - перенос *script* в _Host.cshtml. И тут возникает:

Проблема 2.
Blazor не видит JavaScript. Т.е. страница срабатывает в браузере, но отображает только кнопку "Удалить карту". Самой карты нет. Ошибок приложения тоже нет.

Проблема 3.
Существует способ вызвать JS со страницы Razor, но в Blazor приложение не видит функцию JS, и при вызове дает ошибку.

Кто-нибудь может помочь?

Спасибо.

PS: Blazor **Server**

UPD1: Удалил лог, вряд ли его кто-то смотрел далее 1-й строки.

UPD2: Добавил свое решение

Answer (score 1):

Итак, выполняем следующее:

***1. Html* превращаем в компонент *Razor***, точнее даже в *Blazor*, для чего:

1.1 меняем расширение *.html* на расширение *.razor*

1.2 добавляем в начале страницы:

```
@page "/mapbasics"

@using Microsoft.JSInterop

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
```

1.3 теги *script* переносим в *_Host.cshtml* в *head*

1.4 удаляем тег *head* из *mapbasics.razor*

**2. Добавляем функцию старта в *mapbasics.js***

```
// новый старт
function startmap() {
    // Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
    ymaps.ready(init);
}
```

**3. Добавляем код в *mapbasics.razor***

```
@code {
    // После того как все элементы DOM веб страницы загружены...
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
        if (firstRender) {
             await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("startmap");
        }
    }
}
```

**4. Уточняем вызов компонента в *NavMenu.razor***